# EF Core pulling the same data twice

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, ef-core-2.2

I have a function that sends e-mails to members of my system. Which e-mail they'll get, depends on different conditions.

Lately I've discovered, that it sometimes sends to the same person twice.

My code - simplified:

```
In my startup.cs:

[...]

services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("App")));

[...]


My page:

namespace MyApp.Pages
{

    public class MemberMailsModel : PageModel
    {

        private readonly DBContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public MemberMailsModel(DBContext dbContext, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<PageResult> OnGetAsync()
        {

            var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("SendInBlue");
            var members = await _dbContext.Members.Include(x => x.Logs).Where(x => x.ConsentDate == null).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

            foreach (var member in members)
            {

                bool mail1sent = member.Logs.Any(x => x.Action == "Mail1Sent");
                bool mail2sent = member.Logs.Any(x => x.Action == "Mail2Sent");
                bool mail3sent = member.Logs.Any(x => x.Action == "Mail3Sent");

                if (!mail1sent)
                {                
                    var sibMail = await httpClient.PostAsync(...);
                    sibMail.Dispose();

                    var log = new Log
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now,
                        Action = "Mail1Sent",
                        Text = "Mail #1 sent",
                        MemberId = member.Id
                    }
                    _dbContext.Add(log);
                }
                else if (!mail2sent && mail1sent)
                {                
                    var sibMail = await httpClient.PostAsync(...);
                    sibMail.Dispose();

                    var log = new Log
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now,
                        Action = "Mail2Sent",
                        Text = "Mail #2 sent",
                        MemberId = member.Id
                    }
                    _dbContext.Add(log);
                }
                else if (!mail3sent && mail2sent)
                {                
                    var sibMail = await httpClient.PostAsync(...);
                    sibMail.Dispose();

                    var log = new Log
                    {
                        Date = DateTime.Now,
                        Action = "Mail3Sent",
                        Text = "Mail #3 sent",
                        MemberId = member.Id
                    }
                    _dbContext.Add(log);
                }

                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            }

            return Page();

        }

    }

}
```

I can see in my custom log function, that some members get the same e-mail twice and are added to the log twice at the exact same timestamp, as if the member was in the query twice.

It can happen on any of the conditions on any random member.

How can that be?

Comment: It is age old wisdom not to do any action with side effects in get requests because of these problems. That said, the problem might be most probably in how and when you invoke this.. Are you sure no more than one request is sent to this page?

Comment: `_dbContext.Members.Include(x => x.Logs)` If a "member" has multiple "logs", won't you be getting back multiple records with the same member info? Equivalent to to `Select * from Members m JOIN Logs l on l.memberid = m.memberid` or something like that

Comment: @MatJ I'd be glad if you could be a little more specific what you mean about the side effects? The page is only called by a task on the server every hour. The server calls an url with restriction parameters, så that it can't be called manually.

Comment: @Mads creating data (`_dbContext.Add(log)`) or sending an email would be a side effect of a `GET` operation.

Comment: Thanks @user2051770. So what would be best practice? And no, a member is only pulled once, even if there are many logs for that member. :)

Comment: yeah, ignore my first comment. logs would be a collection on the Member object. I was thinking sql, not EF

Comment: @user2051770 could you explain how I should do it instead? How can I avoid to query and update in the same run?